# How would you design Forums boards models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a question for you guys, I'm inexperienced, still learning, slowly building my portfolio to try and get my first job as a Junior
Currently/

I'm building Discussion forum app.

I'm trying to admin be able assign restrictions to who can view and/or add new posts to each BoardGroup/Board/SubBoard with the lowest child having the highest priority (so if only 4 groups can view BoardGroup, you can still pick for example 2 groups out of these 4 that will be able to view this one certain Board, while other Boards in the BoardsGroup will have view settings same as parent BoardsGroup)

My code is shown below, even though its working it doesn't feel right, I think there is better way to design in, and my question is, how would you design it?

Models:

```
class BaseBoardClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=248, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    """Permissions Groups, if null all users have permission"""
    can_view_group = models.ManyToManyField(Group,
                                            blank=True,
                                            null=True,
                                            help_text="What groups will ba bale to view given this Board/Group "
                                                      " Aviable after creation",
                                            related_name="%(class)s_can_view_group")
    can_add_new_posts = models.ManyToManyField(Group,
                                               blank=True,
                                               null=True,
                                               help_text="What groups will ba able to add new topics to this Board/Group,"
                                                         " Aviable after creation",
                                               related_name="%(class)s_can_add_new_posts")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class BoardGroup(BaseBoardClass):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("boards_app:board_group", kwargs={"board_id": self.id})


class Board(BaseBoardClass):
    """Board group the boards belongs to"""
    parent = models.ForeignKey(BoardGroup, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="boards")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("boards_app:board", kwargs={"board_id": self.id})


class SubBoard(BaseBoardClass):
    #todo better way to behave on_delete
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="sub_board")

    #todo fix absolute url? common ids with board?
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("boards_app:board", kwargs={"board_id": self.id})
```

Admin: - mostly it makes sures that admin can only choose groups for self can_view/can_add from parents can_view/can_add

```
class BoardsBase(admin.ModelAdmin):
    obj = None

    """get object that admin is working on"""
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            self.obj = obj
        return super(BoardsBase, self).get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)

    """Allow to set only groups aviable in Board group, if board group groups are null allow all"""
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if self.obj.parent:
            if db_field.name == "can_view_group" and self.obj.parent.can_view_group.exists():
                kwargs['queryset'] = self.obj.parent.can_view_group
            elif db_field.name == "can_add_new_posts" and self.obj.parent.can_add_new_posts.exists():
                kwargs['queryset'] = self.obj.parent.can_add_new_posts
        return super(BoardsBase, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    """On board creation disable assigning groups as board group is not yet assignied and admin doesn't know yet what
        groups m2m field will be allowed to use"""
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            return ['can_view_group', 'can_add_new_posts']
        elif obj.parent is None:
            return ['can_view_group', 'can_add_new_posts']
        return []



@admin.register(models.Board)
class Board(BoardsBase):
    model = models.Board


@admin.register(models.SubBoard)
class SubBoard(BoardsBase):
    model = models.SubBoard

    """Allow to set only groups aviable in grand parent, if grand parent greoups are null check for parents groups
    if these are null too, allow all"""
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if self.obj.parent.parent:
            if db_field.name == "can_view_group" and self.obj.parent.parent.can_view_group.exists():
                kwargs['queryset'] = self.obj.parent.parent.can_view_group
            elif db_field.name == "can_add_new_posts" and self.obj.parent.parent.can_add_new_posts.exists():
                kwargs['queryset'] = self.obj.parent.parent.can_add_new_posts
        return super(SubBoard, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Signals: - These basically update the children 'can_view'/'can_add_new_posts' so it doesn't have anything more than parents 'can_view'/'can_add_new_posts'

```
"""On BoardsGroup 'can_view'/'can_add_new_posts' change, 
it deletes from related Boards 'can_view'/'can_add_new_posts'
all Groups that are not in the BoardGroup 'can_view'/'can_add_new_posts'"""
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=models.BoardGroup.can_add_new_posts.through)
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=models.BoardGroup.can_view_group.through)
def can_view_changed(instance, action, pk_set,**kwargs):
        if action == "post_remove":
            for i in instance.boards.all():
                i.can_view_group.remove(*pk_set)
                for sub in i.sub_board.all():
                    sub.can_view_group.remove(*pk_set)
        elif action == "pre_add":
            if instance.can_view_group.exists():
                for i in instance.boards.all():
                    i.can_view_group.set(pk_set)
                    for sub in i.sub_board.all():
                        sub.can_view_group.set(pk_set)

#todo test it (if parent was null before does it change)
"""same as above with exception that in only checks Boards in relation of subboards"""
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=models.Board.can_add_new_posts.through)
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=models.Board.can_view_group.through)
def can_view_changed(instance, action, pk_set,**kwargs):
        if action == "post_remove":
            for i in instance.sub_board.all():
                i.can_view_group.remove(*pk_set)
        elif action == "pre_add":
            if instance.can_view_group.exists():
                for i in instance.sub_board.all():
                    i.can_view_group.set(*pk_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but still, I think what you are trying to achieve can be achieved easily using Django Permissions. Under the Auth App, there are user permissions as well as group permissions. Admin can assign those permissions to the user. You can check Django Admin Module to get an idea about how to assign permissions.

You can customize the permissions according to your needs as well. 
you can read about Django Admin module here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/

Also read about permissions -
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, I've been thinking about permissions before, but from what i figured out permissions are assigned to model class not model object, so lest take 'view' permission if i assign it to one group they will be able  to view all boards, when i want to give them access to this, one certain board

Comment: Actually You can use has_object_permission function. Django does not provide an implementation for that, so you can implement it yourself. You can also an object permission backend like django-guardian (uses DB) or my preferred one - django-rules (Does not use DB).

Comment: You can also define your own permission classes. Extend the DjangoModelPermissions and implement your logic in that class. I recently did that in one project